# Checking if same object is already present in a list

Tags: c#, list

Here is the story:

Im trying to make a list of different clusters... I only want to have the necessary clusters... And Clusters can be the same.

How can I add this to a list by checking if the list contains the object (I know objects cant be passed here)

This is my sample quote:

```
foreach (Cluster cluster in clustersByProgramme)
{
    if (!clusterList.Contains(cluster))
    {
        clusterList.Add(cluster);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Your code should work; if it hasn't, you might be using different **object instances** that represent the same actual cluster, and you perhaps haven't provided a suitable `Equals` implementation (you should also update `GetHashCode` at the same time).

Also - in .NET 3.5, this could be simply:

```
var clusterList = clustersByProgramme.Distinct().ToList();
```

---

As an example of class that supports equality tests:

```
class Cluster // possibly also IEquatable<Cluster>
{
    public string Name { get { return name; } }
    private readonly string name;
    public Cluster(string name) { this.name = name ?? ""; }
    public override string ToString() { return Name; }
    public override int GetHashCode() { return Name.GetHashCode(); }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Cluster other = obj as Cluster;
        return obj == null ? false : this.Name == other.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bonus for making the name field readonly, that's the correct way to reimplement GetHashCode(), without the world blowing up ;)

Comment: @Pop- yeah immutable fields are the way to for GetHashCode().

Comment: Sorry - don't like the `name ?? ""` - throw an excpetion instead.

Comment: @Eric- indeed, that is an option (`ArgumentNullException`). I'll be honest; in this example it was mainly to safe space...

Comment: @Marc, is it better to do the name and Name members like you did, or is it better to just have private readonly string Name; and use it everywhere instead?

Comment: If the question is "should I still go via a property, or should I just use a field", then note that the JIT will almost certainly "inline" a basic "return field;" getter - so there is no significant difference. Except that accessing the property is more flexible if you change things later.

Comment: Thanks Marc. That's what I meant. The reason I asked is, I generally try to make things immutable and having a readonly Name field seems more clear to me. I wish ti was possible to have readonly automatic properties.

Answer (score 3):

Your example is about as simple as it is going to get.  The only thing I could possibly recommend is that you use the [`Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca(VS.85).aspx) method:

> The Predicate is a delegate to a
>   method that returns true if the object
>   passed to it matches the conditions
>   defined in the delegate. The elements
>   of the current List are individually
>   passed to the Predicate delegate, ***and
>   processing is stopped when a match is
>   found.***
>
> This method performs a linear search;
>   therefore, this method is an O(n)
>   operation, where n is Count.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using .NET 3.5, use a HashSet to do this.

```
HashSet<Cluster> clusterList = new HashSet<Cluster>();
foreach (Cluster cluster in clustersByProgramme)
{
     clusterList.Add(cluster);
}
```

In this case, also make sure that if cluster1 == cluster2, then

```
cluster1.Equals(cluster2);
cluster2.Equals(cluster1); //yeah, could be different depending on your impl
cluster1.GetHashCode() == cluster2.GetHashCode();
```

Comment: A `HashSet<T>` won't work - the OP's list _can_ contain duplicates, just not certain duplicates.

Comment: Unless I'm misreading the requirements, which I don't think I am.

Comment: Yeah, re-reading the requirments it looks like he is creating a new, unqiue list. In that case a HashSet<T> would be best option, presuming no ordering is required.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but it is not very efficient. You could instead use a `HashSet<T>` like this:

```
HashSet<Cluster> clusterSet = new HashSet<T>();
foreach (Cluster cluster in clustersByProgramme)
  clusterSet.Add(cluster);
```

In this case, also make sure that if cluster1 == cluster2, then

```
cluster1.Equals(cluster2);
cluster2.Equals(cluster1); //yeah, could be different depending on your impl
cluster1.GetHashCode() == cluster2.GetHashCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just use dictionary?

It is n(1) as long as your items have a good hash.

Seems a simple solution

Ie dictionary.Contains(key) is n(1)

you can then update existing if at all or add new